# Pass a column value through to the title of a ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

##### Say I have this tibble:

```
df <- tibble(question_text  = c('Did they do the thing?', 'Did they do the thing?','Did they do the thing?', 'Did they do the thing?'),
             answer_text    = c('They did', 'They did', 'They did not', 'They did not'),
             answer_numeric = c(3, 3, 2, 2),
             gender         = c('Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male'),
             n              = c(82000, 41000, 12000, 39000))

df
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  question_text          answer_text  answer_numeric gender     n
  <chr>                  <chr>                 <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1 Did they do the thing? They did                  3 Female 82000
2 Did they do the thing? They did                  3 Male   41000
3 Did they do the thing? They did not              2 Female 12000
4 Did they do the thing? They did not              2 Male   39000
```

I want to write a function that prints a ggplot graph and which passes through the value of `question_text` to the title. *(in practice my dataset has many more question-answer combinations than in the tibble shown, but the code below replicates the error i'm getting)*.

##### And this is the code I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(viridis)

graph_fcn <- function(catvar, ft_size=12, title, scales){
  df %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(answer_text, answer_numeric), y = n, fill = answer_text)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none',
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text=element_text(size={{ft_size}})) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
    ggtitle(paste0("\"",  question_text, "\"", {{title}})) +
    facet_wrap(vars({{catvar}}), scales={{scales}})
}

graph_fcn(catvar = gender,
          ft_size = 8,
          title = 'by gender',
          scales = 'fixed')
```

If you run the above it will return the error:

`Error in paste0("\"", { : object 'question_text' not found`

I've tried numerous things to try and solve this:

1. Putting `question_text` inside double curly brackets, i.e. `{{}}`
2. Passing `question_text` through to the function argument and setting the default as `question_text`
3. Passing `question_text` through to the function argument and then explicitly setting `question_text = question_text` in the function call

None of the above work though. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong here? And how I can pass the value of `question_text` through to `ggtitle()`?

If I remove `question_text` from the line `ggtitle(paste0("\"", question_text,  "\"", {{title}}))` the graph looks like this:

[image]

##### Addendum

As my `df` actually contains many more question-answer combinations, in practice what i'm doing is performing various mutations and then piping that directly into the ggplot() command, within the function. I.e.

```
graph_fcn <- function(que_id, catvar, ft_size=12, title, scales){
  df %>%
  filter(question_id=={{que_id}}) %>%
  group_by(question_text, answer_text, answer_numeric, {{catvar}}) %>% count() %>% 
  filter(!is.na({{catvar}})) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(answer_text, answer_numeric), y = n, fill = answer_text)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none',
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text=element_text(size={{ft_size}})) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
    ggtitle(paste0("\"",  question_text, "\"", {{title}})) +
    facet_wrap(vars({{catvar}}), scales={{scales}})
}

graph_fcn(catvar = gender,
          ft_size = 8,
          title = 'by gender',
          scales = 'fixed')
```

So if I put `df$question_text[1]` inside ggtitle() it pulls the first value from the main `df` rather than the much smaller one that only contains a single question value.

##### Additional solution:

The below solutions work well for a small df with only one question-answer combination, and Sonak's is great if you want to make plots for all questions. I found the simplest though is actually to assign the dplyr transformations to a `temp_df` within the function, then separately within the function pass the `temp_df` into the `ggplot` call.

I.e.

```
graph_fcn <- function(que_id, catvar, ft_size=12, title, scales){
  temp_df <- df %>%
  filter(question_id=={{que_id}}) %>%
  group_by(question_text, answer_text, answer_numeric, {{catvar}}) %>% count() %>% 
  filter(!is.na({{catvar}}))

temp_df %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(answer_text, answer_numeric), y = n, fill = answer_text)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none',
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text=element_text(size={{ft_size}})) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
    ggtitle(paste0("\"",  temp_df$question_text[1], "\"", {{title}})) +
    facet_wrap(vars({{catvar}}), scales={{scales}})
}
```

Comment: Try `df$question_text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(viridis)

graph_fcn <- function(df, catvar, ft_size=12, title, scales){

    ggplot(df) +
     geom_col(aes(x = reorder(answer_text, answer_numeric), 
                  y = n, fill = answer_text)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
    theme(legend.position = 'none',
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text=element_text(size=ft_size)) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
    ggtitle(paste(df$question_text[1], title)) +
    facet_wrap(vars({{catvar}}), scales=scales)
}
```

You don't need

- `scales={{scales}}`
- `size={{ft_size}})`
- `{{title}})`

Those values can be directly passed.

`df$question_text` has multiple values , it is better to select specific one which you are interested in.

---

To apply the function to multiple question id use -

```
df %>%
  group_split(question_id) %>%
  purrr::map(~graph_fcn(.x, catvar = gender,
                 ft_size = 8,
                 title = 'by gender',
                 scales = 'fixed')) -> list_plots

list_plots
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak. I'm calling this function many different times, and scales, ft_size, and title vary each time. Is it still true that I don't need the curly brackets? On your proposed solution, it works for the small example i've shared, but when I transfer that over to my much larger df it always takes the fist row from the main `df` rather than the filtered, grouped one i'm piping into ggplot(). I'm going to add an addendum to my post to clarify this further. Thanks!

Comment: @C.Robin See the updated function where I pass the dataframe as first argument and apply this function to every question id after splitting the data with `group_split`.

Comment: Thanks. I can probably make this work. I definitely don't want to plot all the questions, but I think I can filter `df` on `question_id` before passing it through to the `group_split`. Feels like there must be a better way of doing this though as once I filter on `question_id` there will only be one question to split on so it's a heavy operation to perform just to call the the value from one column of my tibble. This seems workable though! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Adding df$question_text works:

```
graph_fcn <- function(catvar, ft_size=12, title, scales){
  df %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_col(aes(x = reorder(answer_text, answer_numeric), y = n, fill = answer_text)) +
    # scale_y_continuous(labels = 'comma') +
    theme(legend.position = 'none',
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          axis.text=element_text(size={{ft_size}})) +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE, alpha=0.6) +
    ggtitle(paste0("\"",  df$question_text, "\"", {{title}})) +
    facet_wrap(vars({{catvar}}), scales={{scales}})
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As for Ronak's solution, it works for the small example i've shared but when I transfer that over to my much larger df it always takes the fist row from the main `df` rather than the filtered, grouped one i'm piping into `ggplot()`. I've just added addendum to my post to clarify this further. Thanks!